# preg_replace special chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Im try replace

```
http://site.com/13/new new (2011).html
```

to

```
http://site.com/13/new_new_2011.html
```

Here is my code,

```
<a href="<?php echo $row->id;?>/<?=preg_replace('#[^\w\-]+#','_', strtolower($row->showTitle()))?>.html">
```

**$row->showTitle()** is a title like **New New (2011)**

but problem is because my links now looks like this

```
http://site.com/13/new_new_2011_.html
```

I need to remove last "_" from url _.html

Comment: you gotta replace \s (space) with _ AND \( with ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 <a href="<?php echo $row->id;?>/
 <?=trim(preg_replace('#[^\w\-]+#','_', strtolower($row->showTitle())), '_')?>.html">
```

It will remove any trailing underscore.